# Syncback: USB serial number in destination field?

Tags: usb, backup, syncback

In Syncback Pro, I created a profile that is triggered anytime an USB drive is inserted.

**How can I dynamically create destination folders,

whose name is the USB drive serial number?**

This way I can get a different backup folder for any USB stick.

The variable in the image below does not work.

[image]

I have unsuccessfully tried:

> - %SERIAL%
> - %SERIAL=%
> - %SERIAL=?%
> - %SERIAL=*%

Comment: Did you try using `%DISKSERIAL%` instead?

Comment: `%DISKSERIAL%` does not work either!

Comment: If you're using Windows Vista or later you might also try `%DISKHWSERIAL%`.

Comment: `%DISKSERIAL%` and `%DISKHWSERIAL%` will show `C:` serial number (that is the drive where the destination folder will be created), not `H:`

Comment: Apparently there aren't other serial-related variables (unless you define some yourself). As for `%SERIAL=?%`, the guide says: "For example, if your `D` drive has a serial number of `BC46-F69E` then `%SERIAL=BC46-F69E%Program Files` will be translated at runtime into `D:\Program Files`." The `%SERIALALL=?%` variable is also similar, except it also includes `A:`/`B:` drives. Both aren't useful in your case, though.

Comment: yes. I had read that chapter of the guide, in fact.

Comment: Keep in mind that cheap USB sticks won't have serials, or even if they do, they won't be unique. There are a lot of small vendors taking the "works on _my_ PC" route.

Comment: thanks for your comment: what backup strategy would you suggest then ?